# How can I search json output from tasks

Tags: ansible, json-query

I have a playbook pulling users and groups from windows 2012 using powershell and I convert it to json.

I get the following output

```json
[
    {
        "Group": "Appsupp",
        "Members": [
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\appsuport",
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\userfirst"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Group": "DBAdministrators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Techsupp",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Access Control Assistance Operators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Administrators",
        "Members": "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\Administrator"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Backup Operators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Certificate Service DCOM Access",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Cryptographic Operators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Distributed COM Users",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Event Log Readers",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Guests",
        "Members": "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\Guest"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Hyper-V Administrators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "IIS_IUSRS",
        "Members": "NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR"
    },
    {
        "Group": "Network Configuration Operators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Performance Log Users",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Performance Monitor Users",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Power Users",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Print Operators",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "RDS Endpoint Servers",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "RDS Management Servers",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "RDS Remote Access Servers",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Remote Desktop Users",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Remote Management Users",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Replicator",
        "Members": {}
    },
    {
        "Group": "Users",
        "Members": [
            "NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users",
            "NT AUTHORITY\\INTERACTIVE",
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\userfirst",
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\usersecond",
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\appsupport",
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\techsupport",
            "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\sqlserveruser"
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to have user compared to that data I pulled from the server. For example, I want to know if `appsupport` user exists and which group it belongs to.

I have tried the below `json_query`. FYI, `getgroup.stdout` is the registered result from the task pulling info from the server.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ getgroup.stdout | from_json | json_query('guser') }}"
      vars:
        guser: "[?Members.contains(@, `appsupport`)].Group"
```

What I get is an empty result (while this method worked with other json). What am I doing wrong?

I assume that the problem is the `Members` key in my object as it my contain an empty dictionnary, a single string or a list of strings as recapped in the chosen examples below.

**Single string:**

```json
{
    "Group": "IIS_IUSRS",
    "Members": "NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR"
},
```

**List:**

```json
{
    "Group": "Users",
    "Members": [
        "NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users",
        "NT AUTHORITY\\INTERACTIVE",
        "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\userfirst",
        "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\usersecond",
        "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\appsupport",
        "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\techsupport",
        "WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\sqlserveruser"
    ]
}
```

**Empty dict:**

```json
{
    "Group": "Replicator",
    "Members": {}
}
```

When I use `json_query('[].Members[*]')` it only returns the latest member, not all `Members`.

How can I select the objects from my json result having a particular user in the `Members` field in this kind of situation?

Comment: Are you able to change the source task that extracts the data?. It would be way easier if you had consistent data beforehand. `Members` should always be a list: empty list on empty groups, single or multiple element(s) list if populated. If you can't, you will have to do that  work as an intermediate processing before you make your selection.

Comment: You should also be very careful because your data contains hard-to-spot typos that might drive you crazy. One I just saw: you have two different users `WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\appsuport` (note one missing `p`) and `WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\appsupport`.

Comment: yes Zeitounator, i need to work on the script that pulled the data. For the typo its just because i alter the real data so it not published on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without *json_query*.

For testing, given the *output* in the file, read it and convert the *Members* to lists, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ lookup('file', 'test.data')|from_yaml }}"
    - set_fact:
        mlist: "{{ mlist|d([]) +
                   [item|combine({'Members': _Members|from_yaml})] }}"
      loop: "{{ output }}"
      vars:
        _Members: |-
          {% if item.Members is mapping %}
          {{ item.Members.keys()|list }}
          {% elif item.Members is string %}
          [{{ item.Members }}]
          {% else %}
          {{ item.Members }}
          {% endif %}
    - debug:
        var: mlist
```

gives

```yaml
  mlist:
  - Group: Appsupp
    Members:
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\appsuport
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\userfirst
  - Group: DBAdministrators
    Members: []
  - Group: Techsupp
    Members: []
  - Group: Access Control Assistance Operators
    Members: []
  - Group: Administrators
    Members:
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Administrator
  - Group: Backup Operators
    Members: []
  - Group: Certificate Service DCOM Access
    Members: []
  - Group: Cryptographic Operators
    Members: []
  - Group: Distributed COM Users
    Members: []
  - Group: Event Log Readers
    Members: []
  - Group: Guests
    Members:
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Guest
  - Group: Hyper-V Administrators
    Members: []
  - Group: IIS_IUSRS
    Members:
    - NT AUTHORITY\IUSR
  - Group: Network Configuration Operators
    Members: []
  - Group: Performance Log Users
    Members: []
  - Group: Performance Monitor Users
    Members: []
  - Group: Power Users
    Members: []
  - Group: Print Operators
    Members: []
  - Group: RDS Endpoint Servers
    Members: []
  - Group: RDS Management Servers
    Members: []
  - Group: RDS Remote Access Servers
    Members: []
  - Group: Remote Desktop Users
    Members: []
  - Group: Remote Management Users
    Members: []
  - Group: Replicator
    Members: []
  - Group: Users
    Members:
    - NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
    - NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\userfirst
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\usersecond
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\appsupport
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\techsupport
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\sqlserveruser
```

Now, you can search for the members, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ mlist|selectattr('Members', 'contains', my_user) }}"
      vars:
        my_user: 'WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Administrator'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - Group: Administrators
    Members:
    - WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Administrator
```

---

Next, create a dictionary of all members and the groups they belong to

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        members: "{{ members|d({})|combine({item: _groups}) }}"
      loop: "{{ mlist|map(attribute='Members')|flatten|unique }}"
      vars:
        _groups: "{{ mlist|selectattr('Members', 'contains', item)|
                          map(attribute='Group')|
                          list }}"
    - debug:
        var: members
```

gives

```yaml
  members:
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:
    - Users
    NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE:
    - Users
    NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:
    - IIS_IUSRS
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Administrator:
    - Administrators
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Guest:
    - Guests
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\appsuport:
    - Appsupp
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\appsupport:
    - Users
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\sqlserveruser:
    - Users
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\techsupport:
    - Users
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\userfirst:
    - Appsupp
    - Users
    WIN-U97DIQUENUM\usersecond:
    - Users
```

Then, the searching is trivial, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_user }} is member of the group(s): {{ members[my_user] }}"
      vars:
        my_user: 'WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Administrator'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'WIN-U97DIQUENUM\Administrator is member of the group(s): [''Administrators'']'
```

---

It's possible to search among the members, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_user }} is member of the group(s): {{ _groups }}"
      vars:
        my_user: appsuport
        _keys: "{{ members.keys()|list|select('search', my_user)|list }}"
        _groups: "{{ _keys|map('extract', members)|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'appsuport is member of the group(s): [''Appsupp'']'
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight Vlad! another way round to get better understanding of ansible

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple problems here:

**Problem 1:**
Your data has three different types for `Members`, depending on what is in there:

1. An empty dict (`{}`) if there are no members
2. A string, if there is exactly one member
3. A list of strings, if there are multiple members

As far as I can see, this will not break, but it is not particularly good style. You should always return a list. An empty one, if there is no member, or a list with one element if there is exactly one member or a list of multiple strings, as you already do, if there are multiple members.

**Problem 2:**
In group `Appsupp`, the user is misspelled: `WIN-U97DIQUENUM\\appsuport` (there is a 'p' missing in 'support'), so this will not match.

**Problem 3:**
This is what actually breaks here. Your query has several problems, it should look like this: `[?Members[?contains(@, 'appsupport')]].Group`

The result is

```json
[
  "Users"
]
```

`Appsupp` is not in there due to the spelling mistake mentioned earlier.

You can test your json-path on [this website](https://jmespath.org/?).

Comment: In that case, please accept my answer by clicking the grey check-mark next to it. :)

Comment: Nice, it worked really well...
So basically the problem no 1 is to generate correct result from the Windows Output, For No 2 its just a typo when i alter the data to protect sensitive information. The No 3 is best! Thanks!